# Inline yaml pipeline scripts work separately, but not together

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-yaml-pipelines

The following two inline yaml-pipeline powershell scripts:

```
- pwsh: (get-content -path $(versionHeader)) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "2.0.0.0", '$(major).$(minor).$(patch).0'} | set-content -path $(versionHeader)
  displayName: 'Update build number in header file'

- pwsh: (get-content -path $(versionHeader)) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "20200101000000", (get-date -f 'yyyyMMddhhmmss')} | set-content -path $(versionHeader)
  displayName: 'Update date in header file'
```

are meant to take these two lines

```
[assembly: MyApp.Net.Attributes.AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.0")]                                   
[assembly: MyApp.Net.Attributes.BuildDateAttribute("20200101000000")]
```

and turn them into these two lines (i.e. put new values in the quotes)

```
[assembly: MyApp.Net.Attributes.AssemblyVersion("2.0.185.0")] 
[assembly: MyApp.Net.Attributes.BuildDateAttribute("20200724013502")]
```

(The replacement values vary)

And either script works fine by itself.  But when I try to use ***both*** scripts, one after the other, the second value comes out messed up.

```
[assembly: MyApp.Net.Attributes.AssemblyVersion("2.0.209.0")]                                // correct
[assembly: MyApp.Net.Attributes.BuildDateAttribute("202.0.209.000000")] // ?????
```

Obviously they are somehow interfering with each other but I don't know how.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I should say that I just found that if I reverse the order of the two scripts, it appears to work as desired.  So I guess my problem is "solved"  But I would still like to understand what is wrong with the other order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in powershell's `-replace` - it interprets wildcards, and it happens that `20200101000000` matches `2.0.0.0`:

```
PS> "20200101000000" -replace "2.0.0.0", "zzzzzz"
20zzzzzz00000
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  Do you know if there is some option to replace that can force it to treat things literally and *not* use wildcards?

Comment: I don't think `-replace` has something like that, but you can use the built-in [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0), like this:
`"20200101000000".Replace("2.0.0.0", "zzzzzz")`. This will not interpret wildcards.